# Install a Python package based on active_gpu or version

Tags: bash, shell, installer

I have the following code, is there a way to optimize it/reduce the code?

```
  #!/bin/bash

  if [[ "${active_gpu}" == 'true' ]]; then
    if [[ "${version}" == 'dev-gpu' ]]; then
        pip install "${version}"
    else
        pip install package-gpu=="${version}"
    fi
  else
    if [[ "${version}" == 'nightly' ]]; then
        pip install "${version}"
    else
        pip install package=="${version}"
    fi
  fi
```

Comment: Please explain what this code accomplishes, and what these conditions are. See [ask].

Comment: Install a Python package, based on 2 variables: active_gpu or version. Code is itself explanatory

Comment: @spicyramen You're setting yourself up for some close votes. You should take the 2 minutes to explain in your post what your code is supposed to do even if it can be clarified by looking at the code :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this kind of problem you want to build a command line with variables, and run it only once.

You only have a few cases but the benefits of this approach become apparent as you add more cases: you don't need an exponential number of branches to keep up.

This code does not *exactly* follow the logic of your code but it's probably close enough.  I'm using an associative array to build the `param` variable, and bash regular expressions to test for multiple no-param cases.

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -A gpu_param=( [true]=-gpu )
[[ $version =~ nightly|dev-gpu ]] || param=package${gpu_param[$active_gpu]}==
pip install $param$version
```